# Saved SSH connections in Windows 10 PowerShell

Tags: ssh, powershell, putty

I am trying to set up SSH connections in PowerShell to replace PuTTY. I am able to open PowerShell and connect using the command `ssh mrpeanut@myserver.com -i .ssh\mrpeanut`. However, I was hoping to save that as a connection like I can do in PuTTY so that I can right-click PowerShell and immediately open that connection. Is there a way to do that with PowerShell?

Functionality I'm trying to replicate from PuTTY:

[image: PuTTY saved connections]

Comment: not sure if relevant but maybe a power-shell script with the steps required for log-in..I know it wouldn't be complete with a GUI like putty but I don't think you could really achieve this without the use of GUI that would display your saved connections. Maybe write the script for each log-in case and put them all together in a scripts folder. hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a text file on your Desktop using extension `.ps1` and put your connection string into it. After that you can right click on it and select `Run with PowerShell` to run the script and start the connection.

Don't forget that you cannot use the Putty key format with OpenSSH. You have to convert your private key to OpenSSH format using `puttygen`.

Comment: That gets me pretty close to what I'm looking for. I have PowerShell pinned to my taskbar. Is there a way to right-click the icon and access that `.ps1` file via the jump list?

Comment: Just drag and drop the ps1 file to the Powershell icon to add it to the jump list.

Comment: It just opens PowerShell then immediately closes it.

Comment: Because there's an error during connection. Add a `pause` command to the end of your script to see the error message. Don't forget that you cannot use the Putty key format with OpenSSH. You have to convert your private key to OpenSSH format using `puttygen`.

Comment: I added `pause` to the end of my script but it still closes immediately. (I also removed `-i mrpeanut` so that it should prompt me for a password. I see the red error flashes but it closes too quickly.

Comment: I had to use `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` to allow my own scripts. That seems to work. Thanks!